# Chart.js - each dataset value = different axis

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/), I want to scale a single value from my dataset to a different axis (Not the whole dataset)

As shown in the screenshot, the 4 items have different units (kgs, meters). The last item bar `hehehe [KG]` has the wrong length (should be at `3kg`).

I know it is possible to assign a different axis to different datasets, but that is not what I need.

**Is it possible to apply a different axis to a specific dataset value?**

*Screenshot of my chart*
[image]

Comment: Attaching a code snippet in your questions will be really helpful for SO to help you better. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more

Answer (score 1):

**It is not possible to apply a different axis to a specific value in the dataset.**

As I understand, you want

> `hehehe [KG]` to scale with `[kg]` axis

**You can solve this issue elegantly**, by separating the dataset based on the units and then map each dataset to its required axis.

---

**Code snippet**

```js
Chart.defaults.global.elements.line.fill = false;

var barChartData = {
  labels: ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019'],
  datasets: [{
    type: 'bar',
    label: 'a',
    id: "y-axis-0",
    data: [1000, 2000, 4000, 5000],
    backgroundColor: "rgba(217,83,79,0.75)"
  }, {
    type: 'bar',
    label: 'b',
    id: "y-axis-0",
    data: [500, 600, 700, 800],
    backgroundColor: "rgba(92,184,92,0.75)"
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    label: 'c',
    id: "y-axis-0",
    data: [1500, 2600, 4700, 5800],
    backgroundColor: "rgba(51,51,51,0.5)"
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    label: 'd',
    id: "y-axis-1",
    data: [5000, 3000, 1000, 0],
    backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)"
  }]
};

var element = document.getElementById("myChart");

// allocate and initialize a chart
var chart = new Chart(element, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: barChartData,
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked"
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'label'
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        position: "left",
        id: "y-axis-0",
      }, {
        stacked: false,
        position: "right",
        id: "y-axis-1",
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@2.7.2/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js">
  </script>
  </link>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="myChartDiv">
    <canvas height="400" id="myChart" width="600">
            </canvas>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js">
</script>

</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's not what I need. I don't want to scale dataset to another axis. I want to scale single value from dataset to another axis. Not the whole dataset.

Comment: oh, this is a quite surprising requirement. I suggest you if possible, separate your datasets for each unit type before plotting them. IMHO, Drawing charts with a dataset having different units is not a good practice

Comment: yeah, I guess that's the only way. Thanks for the help nevertheless

Comment: Happy to help :)